# Query Canonical OU names from SQL

Tags: sql-server, active-directory

Is there a way, using SQL, to obtain the canonical name of an organizational unit?  I can't find such an attribute

Comment: The direct *SQL Server-to-Active Directory* interface is being phased out - not a good idea to rely on it. Can you have some .NET code handle this for you, possibly?

Comment: I suppose.  I will have to implement this in an InfoPath form.  I guess I could always wrap it in a web service.  I still have the same issue of getting the canonical names of the OUs in .net